# Matlab path not saving with GUI (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: matlab, unix

I am trying to edit my MATLAB path. I have permission, it does not give me an error when I try to edit via the GUI, but when I close and reopen matlab, the changes are gone.

I have edited ~/matlab/startup.m to include the paths I need the most, and this works, but why can't I edit the path via the GUI?

I assume it is saving my path (because there is no permission warning/error), but it may be that something is destroying those changes, or reverting upon each startup, I guess I'm just not entirely sure where to look.

EDIT: I should mention that I did not set this machine up, and it's a UNIX box that may have other configuration scripts that are messing with the path. (I checked bashrc but there's nothing there that would interfere)

Comment: Are you clicking 'Save' in the GUI after you have added the folder(s)?

Comment: Once you exit the `pathtool`, do you see the new folders when you call `path`?

Comment: @Suever Yes, the added path appears in the command line window ,along with all the others. Additionally when I open the `pathtool` the new folder is in that list also. It appears that when I restart MATLAB, something is modifying the path definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a script that the previous admin put into the machine's global profile that automatically sets the path to include various toolboxes.